# How can I find a RIB code in a SBI passbook?

Tags: money-transfer, transaction

I want my dad to transfer me money from my country which is Ivory Coast (Cote d'Ivoire) in Africa. So they are asking for a RIB code; I don't know to which details it matches in SBI and I can't find it in my SBI passbook. Can someone help please?